# Pergunta sobre os termos relacionados a Data Science é válida?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Na faculdade que estou houve um debate sobre análise de dados, já havia lido bastante sobre Data Science a um tempo atrás, depois de uma breve pesquisa para relembrar, encontrei vários termos, entre eles:

- Data Science
- Data Mining
- Big Data
- Data Analytics
- Data Analysis
- Machine Learning
- Estatística

E por aí vai...

Uma pergunta que esclareça esse monte de coisa que se parece muito um com os outros é válida? Não adentrando muito em cada um para não ficar ampla, mas apenas um breve resumo a fim de os diferenciar, ou dizer que é a mesma coisa

Comment: Acho que já existe aqui uma pergunta sobre isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. uma pergunta no meta ou no SO?

Comment: No meta. Não tenho a certeza mas lembro-me de alguma coisa parecida, mas já antiga.

Comment: Se vc é acadêmico, com todo respeito, deveria saber que há uma diferença entre "a" e "há". O "há" a gente usa para se referir a tempo passado,  e "a" é um artigo feminino. O correto seria "_...sobre Data Science há um tempo atrás_"... Me perdoe se estou sendo muito chato, mas fico triste em ver jovens inteligentes escrevendo errado. Sem falar que "_há tempos atrás_" é redundante, porque não existe "_há tempos pra frente_".... Se já passou, só pode ser pra trás. Mas isso é perdoável :D